# Pressing enter in content editable iframe inserts double spacing in IE11

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> in content editable iframe inserts double spacing in IE11. Works fine in other browsers, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
frames["editiframe"].document.designMode="on";
```

```
<iframe height="500" width="500" name='editiframe'></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rv4VT/

(Simple iframe with `designMode` set to "on")

Comment: That's not double spacing. Chrome inserts a `<div>` for each line, IE inserts a `<p>`

Comment: @Kos Yes...should'nt it be a <div> or a <br> (like FF)

Comment: I don't know what the spec says it _should_ be. However, IE's behaviour of inserting a new paragraph on enter and newline on shift+enter makes perfect sense to me and is consistent with word processors.